# Making portable execution errors

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, mingw

Making portable execution errors.

I have two files: **kernel.c** and **boot.asm**:

**boot.asm**

```
[bits 32]

section .text
    align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002
    dd 0x00
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)

global start

extern main

start:
    cli
    mov esp, stack_space
    jmp main

    hlt

stack_space:
```

**kernel.c**

```c
char *vidmem = (char*)0xb8000; //змінна для відео пам'яті

void printString(void){
    const char *nameOS = "Welcome to CyberDOS";
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (nameOS[j] != '\0'){
        vidmem[i] = nameOS[j];
        vidmem[i+1] = 0x07;
        ++j;
        i += 2;

    }
}
void clearScreen(){
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (j < 80 * 25 * 2){//резервуємо 25 рядків по 80 символів
        vidmem[j] = ' ';
        vidmem[j+1] = 0x07;
        j += 2;
    }
    j = 0;
}   
void main(void){
    clearScreen();
    printString();
}
```

When I tried make executable file using this commands:

```bash
cd C:\Users\Ukraine\AppData\Local\bin\NASM
nasm -f elf32 C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\boot.asm -o C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output\boot.o
gcc -m32 -c C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\kernel\kernel.c -o C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output\kernel.o
cd C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output

gcc -m32 -o kernel.exe -Wl,-e,start boot.o kernel.o
objcopy -O elf32-i386 C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output\kernel.exe C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output\kernel.elf
cd C:/Program Files/qemu/qemu-system-i386 -output output
cd C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test
pause
```

I have an mistakes with **asm** file:

```
C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\output>gcc -m32 -o kernel.exe -Wl,-e,start boot.o kernel.o
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: boot.o: in function `start':
C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\Test\boot.asm:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I see that troubles with extern line, but nothing special I don't see.

Comment: Side notes: 1) on x86 stack grows down, you have no space for stack allocated. 2) jump to main() doesn't put return address on stack. After it exits, it will try to return to undefined address.

Comment: mingw gcc uses a leading underscore on symbols. In your asm file, use `_main`.